# How to determine symbol size in x and y units

Tags: r, par

I would like to know the approximate dimensions of symbol in my plot area. I think that par()$ps only really refers to text size. So how is a symbol size calculated using the cex parameter? For example, below is a plot of a single point of size cex=10. Can i determine its size from the plot devices par parameters?

```
plot(50, 50, ylim=c(0,100), xlim=c(0,100), cex=10)

#click on outer x limits
p1 <- locator(n=1,typ="n")
p2 <- locator(n=1,typ="n")

#approx width in x units(~15)
abs(p1$x - p2$x)
```

Thanks for you help. -Marc

Comment: I believe the answer is somewhere in either `?par` or `?plot` .  In any case, I'd recommend setting the `par` parameters for your plot, rather than retrieving the defaults after the fact.

Comment: That's actually what I'm trying to do. I just included the locator example to show what I expect these values to be.

Comment: If you goal is to generate a plot with symbols of a specified size then you may want to look at the `symbols` function or the `my.symbols` function in the `TeachingDemos` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation contained in `?par`, we have that,

- `cin` - **R.O.**; character size (width, height) in inches. These are the same measurements as cra, expressed in different units.
- `cra` - **R.O.**; size of default character (width, height) in ‘rasters’ (pixels). Some devices have no concept of pixels and so assume an arbitrary pixel size, usually 1/72 inch. These are the same measurements as cin, expressed in different units.

On my machine, these values appear to be:

```
par("cin")
[1] 0.15 0.20
> par("cra")
[1] 10.8 14.4
```

So character magnification via `cex` ought to happen relative to these dimensions, presumably by scaling the horizontal and vertical dimensions separately (although I don't know that for sure).

Comment: Thanks joran. This does get me closer. I think symbols are still treated a bit differently than text characters, but in any case this provides a rough estimate of their size. Cheers