# convert point cex to inches, pixels, or plot coordinates in r

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to convert the point size in cex to units of width and height on the plot. I can work with the units in inches, or pixels, or xy coordinates. I found something similar for finding the size of characters, but I can't find anything for plotted points. If I can figure out the size of a point when `cex = 1` using `par()`, then I can calculate the sizes of differently scaled points too.

For characters, get height and width with:
`par("cin")` inches
`par("cra")` pixels
`par("cxy")` xy coordinates

Are there similar options to get the sizes of points?
OR, how do you convert character height and width into point diameter?

*(Note that this similar question [How to determine symbol size in x and y units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277292/how-to-determine-symbol-size-in-x-and-y-units) only answers for characters and not for points.)*

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/how-big-is-your-graph.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error, it looks like the point diameter (in xy coordinates) is the character height divided by 2*pi.

```
char.height <- par("cxy")[2]
point.diam <- char.height / (2 * pi)
point.cex <- 7 # try changing and it still works
point.diam.cex <- point.diam * point.cex

plot(x = 0, y = 1, type = "n")
points(x = 0, y = 1, cex = point.cex, pch = 21, bg = "grey")
segments(x0 = 0 - (point.diam.cex/2), x1 = 0 + (point.diam.cex/2), y0 = 1, y1 = 1, col = "red")
```